# WooCommerce stripe payment form not translating on checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, multilingual

I am using WooCommerce payment method Stripe for checkout Credit card and for translation I am using **Weglot**  https://weglot.com/ Plugins everything is translating and working fine except the Stripe Fields Labels Like

1. Carte bancaire = credit card
2. Giropay = giropay
3. Numéro de carte =Card number
4. Expire le = Expires on

I also tried using Jquery But it's not working for more detail please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Stripe [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) is in an iframe and is not meant to be manipulated programmatically. While it supports localization, you'll need to work with WooCommerce for help with how to make that work in your own integration.

Comment: I fixed it using the localization hook of wordpress. Thank you